# permalink as content

Tags: permalinks

I have a quick question.

Right now permalink url is automatically set by the title text you enter.

So when your title is i love marry, page url will be www.example.com/i-love-marry

I'm new to coding, but I presume that somewhere in the wordpress code there is a command similar to [permalink][title][/permalink]

Is it possible for permalink to be set by the content instead of the title?

Or is it possible to somehow  modify a custom permalink that instead of /%postname%/ I would be able to set /%postcontent%/

I hope you get the idea.

I have searched everywhere and haven't found the answer.

Would appreciate your help.

thanks.

Comment: Presumably you’re not going to have that much content? Or do you only want the first X words for the link?

Comment: Yeah, content is short, up to 50 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in functions.php of your theme. It's untested in this form, but should work.

```
/**
 * Change the Permalink on save / update
 */
function wpse_297006_rewrite_slug( $post_id, $post, $update ){
  // check if it's a post
  if (!(get_post_type( $post_id ) === 'post')) return;
  // check if it's not a revision
  if (!(wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) === false)) return;

  // check if it's not a revision
  $content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
  // set the args
  $args = [
    'ID' => $post_id,
    'post_name' => strtolower( sanitize_title( $content ) ),
  ];

  // unhook this method to prevent infinite loop
  remove_action('wp_insert_post', 'wpse_297006_rewrite_slug');
  // apply $args when post is saved
  wp_update_post( $args );
  // re-hook this method
  add_action('wp_insert_post', 'wpse_297006_rewrite_slug', 10, 3);
};

add_action('wp_insert_post', 'wpse_297006_rewrite_slug', 10, 3);
```